# Parsing parameters from string using a regex with groups in python

Tags: python, regex

Please, I'm trying to grab some parameters from a string. The parameters start with : or $ and are enclosed between brackets.

Ex:

```
some text [more text :Parameter1] more text [more (:Parameter2)]
```

My goal is to get two matches as the following:

> Full match: [more text :Parameter1]
>
> Group 1: :Parameter1
>
> Full match: [more (:Parameter2)]
>
> Group 1: :Parameter2

The following regex almost works. Except for the cases when the parameter itself is enclosed between parenthesis like Parameter2.

```
r"\\[.*?([:\$].*?)]"
```

and in these cases I get:

> Full match: [more text :Parameter2]
>
> Group 1: :Parameter2)

Note that group1 comes with the last parenthesis.

I couldn't find a way to remove it. Appreciate any help.

[regex101 tests](https://regex101.com/r/UveLFH/4)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the parameter to be between the opening and the matching closing parenthesis, you might make use of [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^][()$:]` to match any character that is not in the character class.

To match either of the possibilities you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) which  will give you 2 capturing groups:

```
\[[^][()$:]*(?:\(([:$][^][()$:]+)\)|([:$][^][()$:]+))\]
```

About the pattern

- `\[` Match `[`
- `[^][()$:]*` Match 0+ times any character that is not in the character class
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(` Capturing group 1

    - `[:$][^][()$:]+` Match `$` or `:`, then match 1+ chars not in the character class
  - `)` Close group 1
  - `\)` Match `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `(` Capturing group 2

    - `[:$][^][()$:]+` Match `$` or `:`, then match 1+ chars not in the character class
  - `)` Close group 2
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJr8R6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

With extended regex pattern:

```
import re

s = 'some text [more text :Parameter1] more text [more (:Parameter2)]'
res = re.findall(r'(\[[^\[\]:$]+\(?([:$][^:$)]+)\)?\])', s)
print(res)
```

The output (in format `(<full_match>, <group_1>)`):

```
[('[more text :Parameter1]', ':Parameter1'), ('[more (:Parameter2)]', ':Parameter2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex does what you want:

`\[.*?([:\$].*?)\)?]`

Output:

```
[more text :Parameter1]
:Parameter1
[more (:Parameter2)]
:Parameter2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a simple expression,

```
(\[[^(:]+([^]]+)\])
```

and then scripting the rest of the problem to avoid look-arounds.

---

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(\[[^(:]+([^]]+)\])"

test_str = "some text [more text :Parameter1] more text [more (:Parameter2)]"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/JU9dxL/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/JU9dxL/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\[[^:]+([:$][^])]+)[])]+)
```

It will be faster than using lazy quantifiers.

Regex details:

- `\[` matches `[`
- `[^:]+` matches 1 or more times any characters but a `:`
- `([:$][^])]+)` second group:

  - `[:$]`matches either `:` or `$`
  - `[^])]+` matches 1 or more times any characters but a `]` or `)`
- `[])]+` matches `]` and/or `)` at least one time

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TuNWgs/1)

```py
import re
s = 'some text [more text :Parameter1] more text [more (:Parameter2)]'

print(re.findall(r'(\[[^:]+([:$][^])]+)[])]+)', s)

Output:
[('[more text :Parameter1]', ':Parameter1'), '[more text (:Parameter2)]', ':Parameter2')]
```